# Browser history navigation

Tags: javascript, html

I would like to go back in browser history until desired page is shown. Something like:

```
while (document.URL!=desiredUrl) {
 history.go(-1);
}
```

How can I do that? 
Using HTML5 pushState() method would be very difficult since I have to catch every user url click and i have mix of different frameworks and iFrames.

br, Simon

Comment: Instead of explain like this, better explain simply what u try to acheive as generic and post your code

Comment: You can't. That's overstepping browser-imposed limitations of JS.